# Как сделать автоматическое переключение звука с динамиков на наушники при их подключении и обратно?

Tags: windows, аудио

Недавно приобрел ноутбук с предустановленной windows 11. При настойке системы подключил наушники (3.5 jack), драйверы установились, но звук не появился. Как оказалось, звук нужно переключать вручную.

В настройках пробовал ставить наушники как устройства по умолчанию, но тогда звук будет проигрываться только в них, и при отключении полностью пропадает, пока либо не переключишься на динамики, либо не подключишь наушники.

Можно ли как-то автоматизировать процесс переключения устройств?

Comment: Вопрос наверное не из тематики данного ресурса. К тому же вы не сказали какие именно наушники (USB, 3.5 jack или беспроводные), какой аудиочип...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась обновлением BIOS.